# Python quiz program. Could you help me identify where I've gone wrong? Thanks

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, random

This is a small quiz program that loops 5 times, every time it loops a different totally random question is asked. I keep getting an error that says (rand_quiz() ) function not defined, although I have defined it. I think I've done it wrongly. Could you help me correct it. Code is below.

```
import random
import operator

operators = {
            "+":operator.add,
            "-":operator.sub,
            "*":operator.mul,
            "/":operator.truediv,
            }

questions = 0
star = 0


def star_score():

    while questions <= 4:
        star = star + 1
        return star


    def check_ans():

        if que_ans == que:
            print("Correct! You earned yourself a star.")
            star_score()

        elif que_ans != que:
            print("Wrong! Better luck next time.")


        def rand_quiz():
            rand_num1 = random.randint(9, 999)
            rand_num2 = random.randint(9, 999)

            ops = random.choice(list(operators.keys()))

            que = int(operators[ops](rand_num1, rand_num2))

            print("What is",rand_num1, ops, rand_num2)
            que_ans = input(">>>")

            if que_ans.isdigit():
                check_ans()

            else:
                return("Error! Invalid input.")    


def quiz_loop():

    while questions <= 4:
        rand_quiz()


quiz_loop()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: You can't get both of those problems from the same code.  `rand_quiz` isn't defined at the top level: you've buried it within `check_ans` and then `star_score`.

Comment: You have a variety of usage errors in this code.  You've "outrun your own legs" -- coded well beyond your current abilities.  I strongly recommend that you adopt incremental programming: write a few lines at a time.  Test each new addition; make sure it works before you go on.  At the moment, you're stuck trying to debug 50 lines of code with at least three fatal errors, *each* of which must be fixed before you will see any recognizable results.  See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help with debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, indentation is very important. You have defined some functions at an indented level. You must define your functions at the base level.